# Grinding malted rye and rye flakes for all-grain

Tags: all-grain, rye, grinding

Do you need to grind flaked rye and malted rye before mashing? Didn't on my first all-grain and I'm not terribly pleased with the lack of extraction. Used the appropriate rests and extra amylase. Ran across a post that Denny did on another site that mentioned grinding malted rye. Is this always necessary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to grind the malted rye to expose the endosperm for gelatinization and 
conversion. Flaked rye has already been gelatinized and can be added to the mash without any pre-processing.

The rye kernel is smaller than barley. I've found that it's best to tighten up your mill a bit to give a good crush.

Comment: If I don't need to precook them, I throw my flakes into the mill along with the malt. Crushing them does no harm and increases the surface area even more which may speed up or improve conversion efficiency.

Comment: I've tried using flaked grains both ways and found absolutely no benefit to crushing them, so I no longer bother.

Comment: For me, the main benefit is that all the grist is weighed out and put in the same bucket for milling. I find it's more of a pain to have to single out an item in the grist as not being milled. But of course, each to their own.

Answer (score 0):

I've brewing for close to 40 years and have never ran flaked rye through the grinder, I just add a 15-20% flaked rye to my mash grain bill.
Since this is the first time I've heard of grinding it, I will try it out on my next brew and determine whether it makes a difference on gravity/taste.
It might extract a bit more of the peppery taste from it, which would be a plus for sure.
This is probably a common mistake.  Getting overconfident will help you make these mistakes!!

Comment: If you try it out, please come back and Edit your anwer to include what you found out.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).